# How to display memory on a C# application

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, byte, binaryreader

I'm trying to make an application that reads memory and displays it. The source of the data is coming from a byte[] array and I've tried converting it into text, but did not work. I also tried to use BinaryReader, but it seems to be only for reading files which isn't what I'm trying to do. If there's a way to read memory other than files with Binaryreader that will help too. I found ICSharpCode.TextEditor.dll that may work, but I don't know how to use it. My main goal is to edit the memory with or without it displaying on the application. If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it!

**List of questions that's related to this topic**

1. How to I display memory visually on the application? e.g. the picture below.
2. What can I use to read memory without streaming a file?
3. What .dll or c# function can I use to make a memory reader/editor that displays or not that reads a byte[].

[This is how I want it to show on application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHoDp.png)

**Here are examples of what I'm trying to do**

```
        byte[] Memory = { }; // Source code
        BinaryReader ReadMemory = new BinaryReader(Memory); // I need it to read byte[] , not a file
        ReadMemory.ReadBytes(10);

        //OR

        byte[] Memorysource = { }; // Source code
        richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Memorysource);
```

Comment: Unclear question. Post code. `but did not work` ??? What happened?

Comment: Ah, you want a hexdump of the bytes. The simplest is `byte[]` and `printf("%02x ", byte)`.

Comment: @Kenney Though a fine suggestion, OP's question is c# not c/c++.  No such beastie as `printf()` in c# sadly

Comment: Try this :              Byte[] data = null;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format("{0,10:X}", bitValue)`

You can also use the BitConverter:

```
BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
```

Comment: `private static string ConvertByteToString(byte[] source)
        {
            return source != null ? System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(source) : null;
        }
            byte[] data = { 0xF2 ,32, 00,00,32, 0xF3, 00, 24, 0xA8, 00, 00, 00 }; // Example

            memoryStr.Text = ConvertByteToString(data); // memoryStr = richTextbox `
**How can I show the 00 (nulls) in as text? Example: byte 0 will come up as a dot.**